# What is wrong with my variegated pittosporum?

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health

All the green-ish leaves visible on the lower branches in the photo is what the plant was when i first got it last year. Ever since, all the newer growth has been slow to come through out the season with pale-ish green leaves that eventually turns yellow and fall off. I decided to repot it and prune off a little of the top growth a few weeks back but now there's this white stuff on all the tips of the branches. Why has this pittosporum performed so badly and what can be done to bring it back to it's old self? The plant is in full sun and is only watered when the soil is dry.[image][image][image][image]